# Populating richfaces ComboBox

Tags: jsf, combobox, richfaces

I am trying to populate a combobox as late as possible, to improve performance. I once had populating methods for all the combo boxes in a page in the constructor of the backing bean. I'd like to populate the combo just when the user needs it. Which is the most indicated event to use and the method to avoid delays and concurrency problems?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

cover both onfocus and onmouseover - in cases of keyboard and mouse usage.
But I would suggest loading it on document.onload.